# Are valence electrons located solely in the s and p subshells?

Tags: physical-chemistry

Or are they in all subshells??

Answer (score 4):

If you define valence electrons as those that belong to open shells, or as those who participate in chemical bonding, then no: The transition metal elements have open $d$-shells, and they play an important role in determining the properties of transition metal compounds.